# Beeline getting stuck on the second command when run through GNU parallel

Tags: hive, stdin, freeze, gnu-parallel

We are trying to run a fixed number of Hive queries in parallel using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).
Even with parallelism set to 1 (i.e. sequential execution) via `-j1` the first execution works, but the second one gets stuck:

```sh
$ parallel -j1 --eta --verbose beeline -e '"SELECT \"{}\";"' ::: a b c
beeline -e "SELECT \"a\";"

Computers / CPU cores / Max jobs to run
1:local / 40 / 1

Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
ETA: 0s Left: 3 AVG: 0.00s  local:1/0/100%/0.0s
+------+
| _c0  |
+------+
| a    |
+------+
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://en02.example.cloud:2181,mn01.example.cloud:2181,mn02.example.cloud:2181/default;principal=hive/_HOST@example.cloud;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;ssl=true;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
21/11/16 10:41:39 [main]: INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Connected to mn01.example.cloud:10000
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 3.1.3000.7.1.6.0-297)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.3000.7.1.6.0-297)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20211116104139_7be8d8ee-f58d-4572-88a4-43533846160b): SELECT "a"
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Created Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:_c0, type:string, comment:null)], properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20211116104139_7be8d8ee-f58d-4572-88a4-43533846160b); Time taken: 0.102 seconds
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20211116104139_7be8d8ee-f58d-4572-88a4-43533846160b): SELECT "a"
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20211116104139_7be8d8ee-f58d-4572-88a4-43533846160b); Time taken: 0.006 seconds
INFO  : OK
1 row selected (0.191 seconds)
Beeline version 3.1.3000.7.1.6.0-297 by Apache Hive
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://en02.example.cloud:2181,mn01.example.cloud:2181,mn02.example.cloud:2181/default;principal=hive/_HOST@example.cloud;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;ssl=true;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
beeline -e "SELECT \"b\";"
ETA: 79s Left: 2 AVG: 42.00s  local:1/1/100%/47.0s
```

Simplifying this further, even a parallel call to `beeline --help` gets stuck for the second run in the same way, so it doesn't seem to be related to the connection to the Hive DB.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions with which we finally got it working is

```
parallel -j1 --eta --verbose beeline -e '"SELECT \"{}\";"' < /dev/null ::: a b c
```

and (thanks @OleTange !)

```
parallel -j1 --eta --verbose --tty beeline -e '"SELECT \"{}\";"' ::: a b c
```

How we found out:
We added a set -x to the beeline bash script and some of the scripts it's calling, logged the results to separate files for the parallel runs and diffed them.
We saw that there was a part in the logs about

```sh
[ -p /dev/stdin ]
```

and below that a few environment variables that got set in the first parallel execution, but not on the second one.
We then played around with various options to give beeline a stdin and the `/dev/null` version finally worked.

Comment: Also try if `parallel --tty -j+0 ...` works for you.

Comment: Hey @OleTange, can you please explain what `--tty -j+0` does? I'm sure people can find out in the man-page, but it would make your comment more useful :)

Comment: Hi @OleTange, the `--tty` parameter seems to work as well, thanks for the pointer!